# Java's error: Could not find or load main class Name while using Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, runtime-error, hdfs, settings

I am trying to launch Hadoop on my computer but when I execute any relating command in CMD such as `hadoop version` or `hdfs namenode -format` I get an error (exact as next):

> Error: Could not find or load main class Name

- The OS is `Windows 10`.
- Hadoop version `2.7.1`.
- `JDK 1.8.0.131`.

I have the following user variables:

```
HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop-2.7.1\bin
HAVA_HOME = C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

And within the system variable `PATH` there are two locations set:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\hadoop-2.7.1\bin
```

In `hadoop-env.cmd` there is variable:

```
JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
```

Among `core-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` links to directories are set only in `hdfs-site.xml`. The full configuration tag in this file is the next:

```xml
<configuration>
<property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>/c:/hadoop-2.7.1/data/namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>/c:/hadoop-2.7.1/data/datanode</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Looks like hadoop libraries are not available in the hadoop classpath, Can you share the output of "hadoop classpath"

Comment: Shouldn't the path be `C:\hadoop-2.7.1\data\dir`  ?

Comment: "hadoop classpath" gives next output:

`C:\hadoop-2.7.1\etc\hadoop;C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;

C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\common\*;

C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\hdfs;

C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*;

C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\hdfs\*;

C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*;

C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\yarn\*;

C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*;

C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*`


but there isn't directory "c:\hadoop-2.7.1\data" because it did not exist in Hadoop package I have downloaded.